# Grouping the ratio by a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like below:

```
    i_id    q_id    week_month
0   1       NaN      27-7
1   2       NaN      27-7
2   3       NaN      27-7
3   4       1.0      27-7
4   5       2.0      27-7
```

I want to basically group by the variable Week_month and get the corresponding ratio of (q_id/i_id_) for that group. Like for above we would have something like

```
week_month   rate
27-7         2/5
```

since q_id has only two valid ids and i_id has 5. So rate is defined as q_id/i_id.

I can do this in sql easily, but I don't want to use Pandsql for this. Any pandas way?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you could just use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html), as `count` will get the total number of non-NA values in each column for each group.

```
df.groupby('week_month').apply(lambda x: x.q_id.count()/x.i_id.count())
```

**Demo**

```
>>> df.groupby('week_month').apply(lambda x: x.q_id.count()/x.i_id.count())

week_month
27-7    0.4
dtype: float64
```

This of course isn't making any assumptions about the actual contents of each group besides non-NA / NA for validity.

Comment: Strange is that you got the output as float while I had to multiply either of numerator or denominator by 1.0 to get the float else it was giving 0 even though q_id is float

Comment: @Baktaawar Hm, interesting, I suppose it depends what exactly you were trying to do.